# How set same sequence number using Row number with 2 columns

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have below table and values and i want the output as below in expected output

```
declare @TestData table (ID int, sku char(6), product varchar(15))
insert into @TestData values (1 ,  'ABDE01'      ,'SPA')
insert into @TestData values (2 ,  'ABDE01'      ,'GRE')
insert into @TestData values (3 ,  'ABDE01'      ,'RUS')
insert into @TestData values (2 ,  'ABAD03'      ,'SPA')
insert into @TestData values (4 ,  'ABAD03'      ,'SPA')
insert into @TestData values (6 ,  'ABAD03'      ,'SPA')
insert into @TestData values (1 ,  'ABAD02'      ,'SPA')
insert into @TestData values (2 ,  'ABAD02'      ,'SPA')
insert into @TestData values (4 ,  'ABAD05'      ,'ENG')
```

The Expected Output as:

```
SKU Product NewRow
ABAD02  SPA 1
ABAD02  SPA 1
ABAD02  ENG 2
ABAD03  SPA 1
ABAD03  SPA 1
ABAD03  SPA 1
ABDE01  SPA 1
ABDE01  GRE 2
ABDE01  RUS 3
```

I tried the following query, but it is not working as expected and it gave me different than what I want

```
declare @TestData table (ID int, sku char(6), product varchar(15))
insert into @TestData values (1 ,  'ABDE01'      ,'SPA')
insert into @TestData values (2 ,  'ABDE01'      ,'GRE')
insert into @TestData values (3 ,  'ABDE01'      ,'RUS')
insert into @TestData values (2 ,  'ABAD03'      ,'SPA')
insert into @TestData values (4 ,  'ABAD03'      ,'SPA')
insert into @TestData values (6 ,  'ABAD03'      ,'SPA')
insert into @TestData values (1 ,  'ABAD02'      ,'SPA')
insert into @TestData values (2 ,  'ABAD02'      ,'SPA')
insert into @TestData values (4 ,  'ABAD02'      ,'ENG')


SELECT
    dt.SKU, dt.Product,  NewRow
    FROM (SELECT
               SKU, Product, --ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY product ORDER BY product) AS RowID,
               DENSE_RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY sku,product ORDER BY id) as NewRow 
              FROM @TestData              
         ) AS dt
```

But i am getting the result as below:

```
SKU Product NewRow
ABAD02  ENG 1
ABAD02  SPA 1
ABAD02  SPA 2
ABAD03  SPA 1
ABAD03  SPA 2
ABAD03  SPA 3
ABDE01  GRE 1
ABDE01  RUS 1
ABDE01  SPA 1
```

Please advise what i missed here. Thanks!!

Comment: I would like to thanks all for your answer and  appreciate your time. The final ordering is not required and the query is working as expected.  :)

Answer (score 1):

You don't want the `PARTITION BY`, only the `ORDER BY`:

```
SELECT dt.SKU, dt.Product,  
       DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY min_id) as NewRow 
FROM (SELECT td.*,
             MIN(td.id) OVER (PARTITION BY sku, product) as min_id
      FROM @TestData td
     ) td;
```

If you just want the sku/product combinations to have different values, the you don't need the subquery:

```
SELECT dt.SKU, dt.Product,  
       DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY dt.SKU) as NewRow 
FROM @TestData td;
```

Answer (score 0):

Is there possible has the following sample data?

```
    insert into @TestData values (1 ,  'ABAD02'      ,'SPA')
    insert into @TestData values (5 ,  'ABAD02'      ,'SPA')
    insert into @TestData values (4 ,  'ABAD02'      ,'ENG')
```

In above situation, how to decide the sort betweent SPA and ENG?

If you has a product sort definition list will be better to deal with the NewRow,For example.

```
     declare @TestData table (ID int, sku char(6), product varchar(15))
    insert into @TestData values (1 ,  'ABDE01'      ,'SPA')
    insert into @TestData values (2 ,  'ABDE01'      ,'GRE')
    insert into @TestData values (3 ,  'ABDE01'      ,'RUS')
    insert into @TestData values (2 ,  'ABAD03'      ,'SPA')
    insert into @TestData values (4 ,  'ABAD03'      ,'SPA')
    insert into @TestData values (6 ,  'ABAD03'      ,'SPA')
    insert into @TestData values (1 ,  'ABAD02'      ,'SPA')
    insert into @TestData values (2 ,  'ABAD02'      ,'SPA')
    insert into @TestData values (4 ,  'ABAD02'      ,'ENG')

    SELECT *,DENSE_RANK() OVER ( PARTITION BY sku ORDER BY x.sort) as NewRow  
    FROM @TestData AS t
    -- definating the sort of product
    INNER JOIN (VALUES(1,'SPA'),(2,'GRE'),(3,'ENG'),(4,'RUS')) x(sort,prd) ON x.prd=t.product
    ORDER BY t.sku,t.ID
```

```
ID          sku    product         sort        prd  NewRow
----------- ------ --------------- ----------- ---- --------------------
1           ABAD02 SPA             1           SPA  1
2           ABAD02 SPA             1           SPA  1
4           ABAD02 ENG             3           ENG  2
2           ABAD03 SPA             1           SPA  1
4           ABAD03 SPA             1           SPA  1
6           ABAD03 SPA             1           SPA  1
1           ABDE01 SPA             1           SPA  1
2           ABDE01 GRE             2           GRE  2
3           ABDE01 RUS             4           RUS  3
```

Answer (score 0):

The closest you can get to your Expected Output using a windowed function is to partition by sku and order by product:

```
SELECT *
, NewRow = DENSE_RANK()OVER(PARTITION BY sku ORDER BY product)
FROM @TestData
ORDER BY sku, ID
```

However, your Expected Output appears to further order by ID, which is not something the windowing function will handle without splitting up the grouping. A cursor loop will probably be the only way to match your Expected Output exactly.